# Minimize $\lceil k / j \rceil (j+1) + 2^j$ as a function of $j$, where $1 \le j \le k$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, optimization, algorithms

Minimize $\lceil k / j \rceil (j+1) + 2^j$ as a function of $j$, where $1 \le j \le k$.

I've programmed an algorithm that I've been trying to analyze for optimal parameters.

Here, $k$ and $j$ are both natural numbers representing the input length and interval length, respectively.

The formula captures the number of multiplications the algorithms performs, and I want to choose $j$ such that it is minimized for arbitrary $k$.

Really, I've no idea on how to approach this problem, except that I'd expect the algorithm to perform best for "small" $j$.

In the case $k = 4$, I get formula output $10, 10, 16, 21$ for $j = 1,2,3,4$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An investigation of the desmos.com graph

https://www.desmos.com/calculator/x66xvqgff3

indicates that for each value of $k$ the minimum value of

\begin{equation}
P(j,k)=\left\lceil\dfrac{k}{j} \right\rceil(j+1)+2^j
\end{equation}

occurs when $j=1.$

So

\begin{equation}
\min\left\{\left\lceil\dfrac{k}{j} \right\rceil(j+1)+2^j{\large\vert}1\le j\le k,\,\,j,k\in\mathbb{Z}\right\}=2k+2
\end{equation}

For any fixed value of $j\,$, $P$ is a non-decreasing function of $k$ with minimum value when $k=j$. And for each increase in the value of $j$, the minimum value of $P$ at $k=j$ increases. Thus for any given value of $k$, the minimum value of $P$ occurs when $j=1$.